# I am unable to get the array values after clicking submit in php

Tags: php

I have an html table that displays certain rows, and each row consists of an email id. I kept a check=box at the end of each row. So user can check any of the check-boxes and click 'send email' button. On submitting an email has to pop up with all the selected emails ids in the 'TO' field.

As of now, I am trying to get the values into an array, and trying to display them. This is for my reference. After that I want to add the mail sending feature.

But my problem is, after checking some check-boxes and clicking submit, my selected emails are not being displayed. It is directly displaying the content in 'else', saying 'no emails are selected'. Thanks in advance.

My code( part of) in html table display page is

```
$i=-1;
if($result222->num_rows > 0){
//echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="db-table">';
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result222);

echo '<table width="100%" id="tblData1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="tablesorter"   boarder-collapse ="collapse">';

echo '<thead><tr bgcolor = "#58B0EB"><th>STUDENT_NAME</th><th>ID_NUMBER</th><th>PHONE_NUMBER</th><th>BRANCH</th><th>YEAR</th><th>CONTACT_PERSON</th><th>EMAIL_ID</th><th>NOTES</th><th><form action="sendemail.php" method="POST"><br/><input id="chk" type="checkbox" name="sel_desel"> </th></tr></thead>';
while($rowz222 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result222)){

echo "<tr>";



foreach($rowz222 as $key=>$value){


if($key=='ci_email') {

$i=$i+1;
echo '<td><a href="mailto:'.$value.'">'.$value.'</a></td>';
$email[]=$value;

}



else{
echo '<td>',$value,'</td>';



}

}
echo '';


echo '<td><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"  name="checklist[]" value=" ' .$email[$i]. '">';
echo $email[$i];

echo '</td>';

echo '</tr>';

echo '<input id="send" type="submit" name="sendemail" value="SEND_EMAIL">';
echo '</form>';
```

My code in 'sendemail.php' is

```
<?php
    session_start();



        if(isset($_POST['checklist'])){

    $arr=$_POST['checklist'];



        echo "The following email addresses have been selected:<br />"; 

            foreach($arr as $selected) 
            { 
                echo $selected; 

            } 




        }


    else {
    echo 'no emails selected';
    }
?>
```

Comment: You are missing the form element

Comment: @MarcinC. My bad Marcin. By mistake I did not include them in the above code. I have echo '<input id="send" type="submit" name="sendemail" value="SEND_EMAIL">';
echo '</form>';  in my code

Comment: form opening with the action? pls edit your question

Comment: and where's the `<form...`?? Post your full code in your question. I for one, won't stand around all day acting as your own personal valet.

Comment: @Fred-ii- <form is in the html table column headers. <th>EMAIL_ID</th><th>NOTES</th><th><form action="sendemail.php" method="POST"><br/><input id="chk" type="checkbox" name="sel_desel"> </th></tr></thead>';

Comment: please Sid; post that in your question and not in comments. Edit your question http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33417002/edit

Comment: `<input id="chk" type="checkbox" name="sel_desel"> ` and you're checking for `$_POST['checklist']` plus, with no array set for the input so your `foreach` is failing. Error reporting would have told you that notice.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am having that particular checkbox to give the user an option to select or deselect all checkboxes.

Comment: Best I can offer is this... Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. You have no POST array matching `sel_desel`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've added it. But still, it is directly displaying the content in the 'else'.

Comment: Replace your `foreach($arr as $selected){...}` with 

`$arr=$_POST['checklist']; 
$array_of_values = explode(",", $arr); 
foreach ($array_of_values as $arrayItem){ echo $arrayItem; }` see if that works. I deleted my other comment. I missed the `$` sign at the end.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did it, but still is the same.

Comment: maybe your query's failing and the way you're fetching it from DB, I don't know and it's much harder to pinpoint the issue without having to setup a db for this. Use `var_dump();` - `print_r()` and echo while looking at your HTML source code (that is a tool in its own right) to see what shows up and being populated in there.

Comment: @Fred-ii- now is working fine..i just made litle change in the sendemail.php. But thank you so much for prompt replies Fred.

Answer (score 1):

Just added `if(isset($_POST['sendemail'])){`  after `session_start();` in the 'sendemail.php' page. Its working.